# xpath select following sibling of td which contents image with alt

Tags: html, xpath

I have following table

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><img src="img/tel.jpg" alt="telephone" /></td>
      <td>111 222 333</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><img src="img/email.jpg" alt="email" /></td>
      <td>user@example.com</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I need to use xpath. How to write the path? I need to display the number. This is the sibling of td which contains the image with alt telephone. So the output should be 111 222 333.

I tried

```
//tr/td/following-sibling::td/img[@alt="telephone"]
```

But I failed. The path `//tr/td/img[@alt="telephone"]` is OK. So I don't know how to tell that I want to display following sibling of this element.

Comment: Is this the only table in HTML?

Comment: @Borna No, it isn't. But it is only table that contains tds with these alt attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"//table/tr/td[./img[@src='img/tel.jpg' and @alt='telephone']]/following-sibling::td"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will work for you:

```
//tr/td/img[@alt="telephone"]/../following-sibling::td
```

or the explicit TD parent:

```
//tr/td/img[@alt="telephone"]/parent::td/following-sibling::td
```